# parentheses when querying SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to ask because i can't find solution for my problem.
I have example query (sql server):

```
SELECT ad_nr FROM ad LEFT JOIN ku ON ku.NR = ad.NR
LEFT JOIN kd ON kd.NR_1 = adNR 
LEFT JOIN bb ON bb.NR = kd.NR_1 
WHERE 
    KD_DATE >= 170701 AND 
AND (bb.BB = 20 OR bb.BB = 21 OR bb.BB = 22 OR bb.BB =23)    /* <- THIS IS THE PROBLEM!! */
( 
  ( 
    ku_6 + ku_5 + ku_4 + ku_3 
  ) BETWEEN 0 AND 6300
 ) GROUP BY AD_KUNDNR
```

I tried even that (but it does not make sense)

```
SELECT ad_nr FROM ad LEFT JOIN ku ON ku.NR = ad.NR
LEFT JOIN kd ON kd.NR_1 = adNR 
LEFT JOIN bb ON bb.NR = kd.NR_1 
WHERE 
    KD_DATE >= 170701 AND 
AND bb.BB = 20 OR bb.BB = 21 OR bb.BB = 22 OR bb.BB =23    /* <- WITHOUT brackets */
( 
  ( 
    ku_6 + ku_5 + ku_4 + ku_3 
  ) BETWEEN 0 AND 6300
 ) GROUP BY AD_KUNDNR
```

I tried two more times but don't remember...

The problem is whatever i do, query does not take into account the values in brackets (`BB = ...`) - it is as if it was not there at all

I want something like that:

```
 SELECT ... WHERE DATE is later than 170701 
        AND one of the listed BB (BB == 20 OR BB ==21 ...) 
         AND (ku_6 + ku_5 + ku_4 + ku_3) is between 0 AND 6300
```

I hope You understand...

Comment: There is syntax for that: `BB IN (20, 21, 22, 23)`

Comment: I suspect your problem is that you're filtering on the inner side of the left joins.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Your AND BB = 20 OR BB = 21 OR BB = 22 OR BB =23  is ambigous .. BB is a table alias  and not a column  name  ..  add a proper data sample .. the correct tables schema and the expected  result

Comment: Have you tried `LEFT JOIN bb` bb table use alias?

Comment: it's only an example and there is no problem with `JOIN` or `ambigous`...the problem is the bracket i think... i will provide some sample data

Comment: @Kafus . . . Your `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` do not match.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem are superfluous or missing ANDs:

```
...
WHERE 
    KD_DATE >= 170701 AND /* another AND follows on next line! */
AND (bb.BB = 20 OR bb.BB = 21 OR bb.BB = 22 OR bb.BB =23)    /* Missing AND here */
( 
  ( 
    ku_6 + ku_5 + ku_4 + ku_3 
  ) BETWEEN 0 AND 6300
 )
```

Another problem is that you are selecting a column not in the group-by list that has no aggregate function applied to it. You can correct it in several ways

```
SELECT MAX(ad_nr)
...
GROUP BY AD_KUNDNR
```

or group by the same column as in the select list

```
SELECT ad_nr
...
GROUP BY ad_nr
```

This is equivalent to

```
SELECT DISTINCT ad_nr
/* without GROUP BY */
```

The corrected query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ad_nr
FROM
    ad
    LEFT JOIN ku
        ON ku.NR = ad.NR
    LEFT JOIN kd
        ON kd.NR_1 = ad.NR
    LEFT JOIN bb
        ON bb.NR = kd.NR_1
WHERE 
    KD_DATE >= 170701 AND 
    bb.BB IN (20, 21, 22, 23) AND
    (ku_6 + ku_5 + ku_4 + ku_3) BETWEEN 0 AND 6300
```

I also used `IN (list)` instead of a long OR chain.